# How to bind Lua with Mecab?

Tags: lua, bind, swig, mecab

I want to use [Mecab](http://code.google.com/p/mecab/) in Lua,but I really can't figure out the procedure of bindings,i am work no windows 7,is bingdings meaning that to create a shared library? if so? how to?i see some binding files about Java,the  files in  package org.chasen.mecab shows that it create by swig,it make me confused.so where does it derive from ? or just write by ourself?after bindings,what else should i do if i want to use in Lua,by the way I use mingw.can someone give some simple steps to me that I can keep trying to work on it.

to greatwolf:
i use followings command to do it

```
swig -lua  -c++ MeCab.i
g++ -c MeCab_wrap.cxx -I C:\Lua\5.1\include -I ..\src
g++ -LC:\Lua\5.1\lib -shared MeCab_wrap.o -llua51  -o MeCab.dll
```

and i got errors below.

```
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2960): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12createTaggerEPKc'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2981): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12getLastErrorEv'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x29c9): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12createTaggerEPKc'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x29d9): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12getLastErrorEv'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2a8d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab11createModelEPKc'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2aae): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12getLastErrorEv'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2af6): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab11createModelEPKc'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2b06): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab12getLastErrorEv'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x2b6d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MeCab13createLatticeEv'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11050): undefined reference to `MeCab::Model::version()'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11457): undefined reference to `MeCab::Model::create(int, char**)'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x11732): undefined reference to `MeCab::Model::create(char const*)'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x122bf): undefined reference to `MeCab::Tagger::parse(MeCab::Model const&, MeCab::Lattice*)'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x17737): undefined reference to `MeCab::Tagger::create(int, char**)'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x17a12): undefined reference to `MeCab::Tagger::create(char const*)'
 MeCab_wrap.o:MeCab_wrap.cxx:(.text+0x17d83): undefined reference to `MeCab::Tagger::version()'
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

it seems that these function declared in mecab.h，but i don't know how to handle it.

Comment: In your MeCab install directory, there's a 'bin' containing `libmecab.dll` and in 'sdk' containing an import library 'libmecab.lib'. You can try linking against one of those but not sure it'll work. Apparently, the provided binary is built with msvc and so the mangled symbols probably won't work with mingw. You'll likely need to rebuild mecab from source using mingw.

Comment: i got same errors,rebuilding is another big problem to me.

Comment: That's the problem with c++. Binaries built with one c++ toolchain won't work with another due to differences in [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). At this point you have two choices: rebuild mecab from source using mingw and link the bindings to that or install msvc and compile mecab lua bindings using msvc instead. Personally, I would prefer the former approach since you already got mingw setup ready to go whereas the latter would involve installing couple hundred megs of extra software -- visual studio is not exactly a lightweight install.

Comment: after a long thinking,I still have no idea about how to build MeCab in Windows.could you give me some tips?I just don't know where to start it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mecab provides a [swig file](https://code.google.com/p/mecab/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fmecab%2Fswig) for automatically generated bindings. As luck would have it, lua is one of swig's supported targets.

A reasonable starting point would be to check out the corresponding makefile to see how bindings get created for other languages. From [mecab's swig makefile](https://code.google.com/p/mecab/source/browse/trunk/mecab/swig/Makefile):

```
SWIG = swig
PREFIX = MeCab

all: perl ruby python java csharp

# ...

perl:   
    $(SWIG) -perl -shadow -c++ $(PREFIX).i
    mv -f $(PREFIX)_wrap.cxx ../perl
    mv -f $(PREFIX).pm ../perl

ruby:   
    $(SWIG) -ruby -c++ $(PREFIX).i
    mv -f $(PREFIX)_wrap.cxx ../ruby/$(PREFIX)_wrap.cpp

python: 
    $(SWIG) -python -shadow -c++ $(PREFIX).i
    mv -f $(PREFIX)_wrap.cxx ../python
    mv -f $(PREFIX).py ../python

# ...
```

Extrapolating from the above, you can try generating swig bindings something like the following:

```
swig -lua -shadow -c++ MeCab.i
```

This will substantially reduce the effort you would otherwise need from manually creating the bindings yourself.

Comment: It just make a file that named ***_wrap.cxx,and I still can't figure out the clear steps to Make MeCab work on lua.

Comment: @user2666334 What you need to do is generate the bindings(MeCab.i -> swig -> MeCab_wrap.cxx) and compile the generated bindings with mingw(MeCab_wrap.cxx -> mingw -> MeCab.dll).

Comment: I am stucking in (MeCab_wrap.cxx -> mingw -> MeCab.dll) i try a lot,but still don't know what files need inculde,what libraries need to link.use g++ to make,does it right?the cmd tells me something like MeCab::Tagger::create(int, char**)' i see the [mecab-doc](http://mecab.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mecab/doc/bindings.html) ,it says something about interface,should i write any files?

Comment: @user2666334 Please add where and how you're stuck to your question. Comment is a poor place to put this information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Lua bindings for mecab. Try googling for them first.

To create the bindings yourself you must be proficient both with [Lua C API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4) and C (or C++). A deep understanding of Lua itself (the language, I mean) is advisable.

Search the [Lua WIKI](http://lua-users.org/wiki/) for some more pointers. In particular [BindingCodeToLua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua) page.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this and since I didn't find anything I wrote a [module](https://github.com/polm/lua-mecab) so you can use Mecab with Lua.

It works like this:

```
mecab = require "mecab" 
parser = mecab:new("") -- you can pass mecab config options here, like "-Owakati"

print(parser:parse("吾輩は猫である"))
```

You can also install it via LuaRocks as `mecab`.

It just provides access to the `parse` method of the `Tagger` class, but when working with Mecab that's all I've ever needed. If you'd like support for other Mecab features please feel free to file an issue on Github.